# passing data from .when to .then in jQuery

Tags: jquery, promise, .when

I'm trying to use a `.when` with an `.each` to loop through some elements and `.then` do something with the results. But I'm not sure how to store the results from the `.when` to use in the `.then`.

for example

```
var widget_data = [];

$.when(
    $.each(widget_ids, function(index, widget_id){
        $.get('/widget/' + widget_id, function(data){
            widget_data.push(data);
        });
    })
)
    .then(function(){
        console.log(widget_data);
    });
```

The widget_data array is empty after running.

Comment: So what's happening with the above approach?

Comment: I see the XHR requests happen after the console.log, and widget_data is empty

Comment: Keep a `console.log(data)` inside `$.get` and see whether you are getting `data` there

Comment: console.log(data) inside the `.when` works and shows the resulting data. it seems `.then` is run right away without waiting for the `.when` to finish.

Comment: try `.done` instead of `.then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) not [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
var widget_data = [];
$.when.apply($,
    $.map(widget_ids, function(widget_id, index) {
      return $.get('/widget/' + widget_id, function(data) {
        widget_data.push(data);
      });
    })
  )
  .then(function() {
    console.log(widget_data);
  });
```

When you use `.each()`, it returns the array which was passed to it, since it is not an promise object, `$.when()` will consider it as resolved and will call the `then` handler without waiting for the ajax requests to complete.

You can use `$.map()` to create an array of promise objects from the source array, which can be passed to `$.when()` as above, in that case the then handler will be called only after all the requests are completed - but note that the order of values in the result array may not match the order of items in the source array.

Comment: Thanks! that worked great. Any thoughts on Gaby's solution? seems to produce the same results.

Comment: @waspinator thet are the same, only the apis used to create the promise array is different

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that `when` needs to get `deferered` as a parameter(s), and `$.each` does not return one.

```
var promises = [];
$.each(widget_ids, function(index, widget_id){
    promises.push( $.get('/widget/' + widget_id, function(data){
        widget_data.push(data);
    }) );
});

$.when.apply($, promises);
 .then(function(){
    console.log(widget_data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! both yours and Arun's solutions work. Any thoughts on his?